# CSS Greyscale On Background Image with Positioned Layers

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, z-index, css-filters

I'm building a website with a 3-by-whatever grid of 16x9 video thumbnails using flexbox. I want to create rollover where the colorful thumbnail turns monotone (greyscale + a x% transparent color layer) with a white logo above it.

Despite my best efforts, the greyscale affects the separate color layer as well.

Here's how I want it to work: I want just the colorful videos thumbnails to appear as a grid. Then, when you hover over them, they desaturate to a monotone color with a white SVG logo centered in each thumbnail.

The way I'm doing this (which could be completely wrong) is this:
1) Create a flexbox of 3-by-whatever thumbnails, with each thumbnail set to a fixed ratio of 16x9. (For this, I'm using the height: 0, padding 56.25 technique found here: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

2) Set the background image of each individual flexbox by giving it its own id tag and setting it in a corresponding css. (background: url(example.png) top left / 100%;) Also set the position to relative. On hover, filter: greyscale(100%).

3) Create a child div inside with an absolute position and a top:0, left: 0, and height & width of 100%. On hover, give that layer a background with opacity and set it on the z-index to 2.

I've read on many other stack overflows that you should be able to set the z-index for one layer to prevent the filter from affecting the other. But whenever I try it, the filter simply affects both divs.

Relevant html:

```
<main class="site-content">
    <section class="video-thumbs">
        <div class="stills-photo" id="client-1-photo"><div class="stills-logo" id="client-1-logo"></div></div>
        <div class="stills-photo" id="client-2-photo"><div class="stills-logo" id="client-2-logo"></div></div>
        <div class="stills-photo" id="client-3-photo"><div class="stills-logo" id="client-3-logo"></div></div>
    </section>
</main>
```

```
.site-content {
/* Establishes a main div for video thumbnails, with a max-width of 1300px. */
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1300px;
}

.video-thumbs {
/* Flexbox for a grid of video thumbnails. Left-most and right-most thumbnails
are flush with the walls of .siteContent. */
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.stills-photo {
/* Sets up flex containers to flow 3 thumbnails per line, 
with a "margin" of 30px between each thumbnail. */ 
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 0;
    width: calc(1/3*100% - (1 - 1/3)*30px);
    height: 0;
    padding: calc(1/3*56.25% - (1 - 1/3)*30px) 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.stills-logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


#client-1-logo:hover {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wikipedia-logo-white.svg) center center / 45% no-repeat, rgb(255, 0, 0, .3);
    transition: .3s;
    transition-property: background-color;
  z-index: 99;
}

#client-1-photo {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/4dKVVXd/example-photo-1.png) top left / 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  z-index: 1;
}

#client-2-logo:hover {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wikipedia-logo-white.svg) center center / 45% no-repeat, rgb(255, 0, 0, .3);
    transition: .3s;
    transition-property: background-color;
  z-index: 99;
}

#client-2-photo {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rft8jSV/example-photo-2.png) top left / 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  z-index: 1;
}

#client-3-logo:hover {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wikipedia-logo-white.svg) center center / 45% no-repeat, rgb(255, 0, 0, .3);
    transition: .3s;
    transition-property: background-color;
  z-index: 99;
}

#client-3-photo {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/Ryjkryn/example-photo-3.png) top left / 100%;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I set this up in a codepen to better see the problem:
https://codepen.io/czeins/pen/OKxBBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes sense that if you filter a parent it also affects its child. I have not heard about being able to do anything differently to stop that, and if you could, it would be a bit hacky and complicated.

The easier way would be to try to separate out your different layers and control them individually. Pseudo elements will help us avoid introducing several new divs here.

The approach:

- `::after` pseudo element gets the background image and a `filter` transition
- `::before` pseudo element gets the overlay logo and an `opacity` transition
- As we hover a thumbnail, the `::after` transitions to grayscale while the `::before` fades in

Doing all that while also grouping repeated styles together to dry out your code (relevant code moved to the top):

```css
.stills-logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.stills-logo::before,
.stills-logo::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.stills-logo::before {
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Wikipedia-logo-white.svg) center center / 45% no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.stills-logo::after {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: filter .3s ease;
}

.stills-logo:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.stills-logo:hover::after {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

#client-1-photo .stills-logo::after {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/4dKVVXd/example-photo-1.png) top left / 100%;
}

#client-2-photo .stills-logo::after {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rft8jSV/example-photo-2.png) top left / 100%;
}

#client-3-photo .stills-logo::after {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/Ryjkryn/example-photo-3.png) top left / 100%;
}


/* layout stuff not related to the hover effect */

.site-content {
  /* Establishes a main div for video thumbnails, with a max-width of 1300px. */
  margin: auto;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.video-thumbs {
  /* Flexbox for a grid of video thumbnails. Left-most and right-most thumbnails
are flush with the walls of .siteContent. */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.stills-photo {
  /* Sets up flex containers to flow 3 thumbnails per line, 
with a "margin" of 30px between each thumbnail. 

If I just used a width of calc(1/3*100%), all 3 thumbnails
would be perfectly flush with one another. 

There are three thumbnails with two spaces between (AKA two gutters): 
one between the first and second thumbnail, and one between the 
second and third thumbnail.

If you subtract 30px from the width, calc(1/3*100%), that amounts
to 90px of blank space (one for each of the three videos) split 
between two gutters (remember: "space-between"). Since I only want
to specify what the length two gutters (and not three), I multiply by 2/3. 

To keep a responsive ratio without placing an image in the div,
I've set the padding to 56.25%, which is 9/16.
(More info: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) */
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  width: calc(1/3*100% - (1 - 1/3)*30px);
  height: 0;
  padding: calc(1/3*56.25% - (1 - 1/3)*30px) 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<main class="site-content">
  <section class="video-thumbs">
    <div class="stills-photo" id="client-1-photo">
      <div class="stills-logo" id="client-1-logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stills-photo" id="client-2-photo">
      <div class="stills-logo" id="client-2-logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stills-photo" id="client-3-photo">
      <div class="stills-logo" id="client-3-logo"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you for the fast feedback and help, stranger.